# Quantifying the Performance of Garbage Collection vs. Explicit Memory Management

Tags: c#, java, c++, memory, garbage-collection

I found this article here:

***Quantifying the Performance of Garbage Collection vs. Explicit Memory Management***

http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/gcvsmalloc.pdf

In the conclusion section, it reads:

> Comparing runtime, space consumption,
>   and virtual memory footprints over a
>   range of benchmarks, we show that the
>   runtime performance of the
>   best-performing garbage collector is
>   competitive with explicit memory
>   management when given enough memory.
>   **In particular, when garbage collection
>   has five times as much memory as
>   required, its runtime performance
>   matches or slightly exceeds that of
>   explicit memory management. However,
>   garbage collection’s performance
>   degrades substantially when it must
>   use smaller heaps.** With three times as
>   much memory, it runs 17% slower on
>   average, and **with twice as much
>   memory, it runs 70% slower.** Garbage
>   collection also is more susceptible to
>   paging when physical memory is scarce.
>   In such conditions, all of the garbage
>   collectors we examine here suffer
>   order-of-magnitude performance
>   penalties relative to explicit memory
>   management.

So, if my understanding is correct: if I have an app written in native C++ requiring 100 MB of memory, to achieve the same performance with a "managed" (i.e. garbage collector based) language (e.g. Java, C#), the app should require 5*100 MB = 500 MB?
(And with 2*100 MB = 200 MB, the managed app would run 70% slower than the native app?)

Do you know if current (i.e. latest Java VM's and .NET 4.0's) garbage collectors suffer the same problems described in the aforementioned article? Has the performance of modern garbage collectors improved?

Thanks.

Comment: The garbage collector uses a "best guess" algorithm to determine when to dispose of memory. The algorithms it uses are not necessarily tuned to what is happening inside your specific program. When you are managing the memory yourself, you get to be more selective and intelligent about how the memory gets collected, but that requires more skill and effort, and you run the risk of memory leaks if it's not done properly.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Actually I think that in C++, thanks to destructors, RAII and smart pointers, it is hard to leak something (being them memory resources or resources of other kinds). In fact, while in Java you could miss releasing a resource in a try...finally block, in C++ the destructors of variables allocated on the stack (or of smart pointers) are automatically called. (Of course, this assumes that classes are properly designed, and each class releases its own resources in its destructor.)

Comment: Thus my statement, "...if it's not done properly."

Comment: I haven't read the article, but isn't the 70% considering memory management overhead only? So the application will not run 70% slower, it'll just spend 70% more time managing memory (which is likely to be a fraction of the total execution time to begin with)

Comment: It can be a pretty big fraction; most of the profiles I've run on large realtime apps showed about 5-15% of total execution time inside memory management. And those were cases where people wrote them worrying about performance from the start.

Comment: Does anyone have a reference to a paper where the authors discuss some of the things that they explicitly didn't cover? Comparisons of some more of the different ways of handling allocation (e.g., regions) and GC algorithms (e.g., concurrent GC) would be particularly interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be asking two things:

- have GC's improved since that research was performed, and
- can I use the conclusions of the paper as a formula to predict required memory.

The answer to the first is that there have been no major breakthroughs in GC algorithms that would invalidate the general conclusions:

- GC'ed memory management still requires significantly  more virtual memory.
- If you try to constrain the heap size the GC performance drops significantly.
- If real memory is restricted, the GC'ed memory management approach results in substantially worse performance due to paging overheads.

However, the conclusions cannot really be used as a formula:

- The original study was done with JikesRVM rather than a Sun JVM.
- The Sun JVM's garbage collectors have improved in the ~5 years since the study.
- The study does not seem to take into account that Java data structures take more space than equivalent C++ data structures for reasons that are not GC related.

On the last point, I have seen a presentation by someone that talks about Java memory overheads.  For instance, it found that the minimum representation size of a Java String is something like 48 bytes.  (A String consists of two primitive objects; one an Object with 4 word-sized fields and the other an array with a minimum of 1 word of content.  Each primitive object also has 3 or 4 words of overhead.)  Java collection data structures similarly use far more memory than people realize.

These overheads are not GC-related *per se*.  Rather they are direct and indirect consequences of design decisions in the Java language, JVM and class libraries.  For example:

- Each Java primitive object header<sup>1</sup> reserves one word for the object's "identity hashcode" value, and one or more words for representing the object lock.
- The representation of a String has to use a separate "array of characters" because of JVM limitations.  Two of the three other fields are an attempt to make the `substring` operation less memory intensive.
- The Java collection types use a lot of memory because collection elements cannot be directly chained.  So for example, the overheads of a (hypothetical) singly linked list collection class in Java would be 6 words per list element.  By contrast an optimal C/C++ linked list (i.e. with each element having a "next" pointer) has an overhead of one word per list element.

---

<sup>1 - In fact, the overheads are less than this on average.  The JVM only "inflates" a lock following use & contention, and similar tricks are used for the identity hashcode.  The fixed overhead is only a few bits.  However, these bits add up to a measurably larger object header ... which is the real point here.</sup>

Comment: Java strings can have their character arrays allocated in “interesting” ways (e.g., literals). There's a lot going on in the background that the API hides.

Comment: @Donal - true, but my point is that differences in Java vs C++ memory requirements are not *just* attributable to the way that memory management is done.

Comment: I'd agree with that. It's an area where the difference between good code and poor code is rather subtle, and that's true in many languages.

Comment: @DonalFellows - but it is not just "good code versus poor code".  For instance you can implement a linked list by adding a `next` pointer field to the class of the object you want to enlist.  That significantly reduces the list space overheads.  But it also breaks down the abstraction boundary between the element class and list class, and that has larger consequences.  It is actually a trade-off between clean design and memory usage / performance.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing _per se_ but I'd point out that the problem with putting a `next` field in is that it pretty much constrains the object to being only a member of a single (linked) list. Sometimes that's OK, but that's typically only when the class is just a concealed part of the implementation of some larger class.

Comment: @DonalFellows - that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: One needs to add that in this study a mark-and-sweep GC was used that itself is implemented in _Java_! So it is in no way comparable to the mark-and-compact GCs that Java is using which are written in highly optimized C (and afaik assembler) code.

Comment: And not to forget, before Java 9, `String`s in Java used UTF-16 all the way, which requires two times as much space as the 8 bit encodings widely used in C/C++. Even where Unicode matters, UTF-8 is often used, which works very well if don’t have to maintain an API that promises random access to UTF-16 units in a fundamental class…

Answer (score 10):

> if I have an app written in native C++
>   requiring 100 MB of memory, to achieve
>   the same performance with a "managed"
>   (i.e. garbage collector based)
>   language (e.g. Java, C#), the app
>   should require 5*100 MB = 500 MB? (And
>   with 2*100 MB = 200 MB, the managed
>   app would run 70% slower than the
>   native app?)

Only if the app is bottlenecked on allocating and deallocating memory. Note that the paper talks exclusively about the performance of the *garbage collector* itself.

Comment: For context, most of the large realtime apps I've worked on spent about 10-15% of their time on managing memory when relying on the OS or standard runtime's allocators. I've seen that number fall to about 5% when using fixed heaps, block allocators, a variety of tough optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

Michael Borgwardt is kind of right about if the application is bottlenecked on allocating memory. This is according to Amdahl's law.

However, I have used C++, Java, and VB .NET. In C++ there are powerful techniques available that allocate memory on the stack instead of the heap. Stack allocation is easily a hundreds of times faster than heap allocation. I would say that use of these techniques could remove maybe one allocation in eight, and use of writable strings one allocation in four.

It's no joke when people claim highly optimized C++ code can trounce the best possible Java code. It's the flat out truth.

Microsoft claims the overhead in using any of the .NET family of languages over C++ is about two to one. I believe that number is just about right for most things.

HOWEVER, managed environments carry a particular benefit in that when dealing with inferior programmers you don't have to worry about one module trashing another module's memory and the resulting crash being blamed on the wrong developer and the bug difficult to find.

Comment: From what I remember, allocation in C# is very, very fast.  It's the GC collection & compaction processes that hurt.

Comment: On pretty much any halfway decent garbage collector, heap allocation is just bumping a pointer, i.e. it is *exactly* the same as stack allocation. What is generally expensive is the actual collection of actual garbage, or more specifically, the actual collection of actual *old* garbage. That's why GCs run best with large heaps: they simply like to avoid collecting.

Comment: @Jörg: I know that. In stack allocation, both allocate and free is one instruction for all objects on the stack frame.

Comment: To be fair, memory that could be allocated on the stack usually has a short lifetime, so will be collected during the first GC cycle, which usually employs a mark & copy collector, whose execution time does not depend on the number or size of freed objects, but only on number and size of live objects. Allocating short lived objects taxes the garbage collector very little, it's the long lived objects that are expensive to collect. And these are allocated on the heap in C++, where allocation / freeing involves bookkeeping, too.

Comment: FYI, if the unmanaged heap is allowed to waste RAM equal to allocated RAM, it can change both allocate and free operations to be O(log (n)) where n is the number of distinct powers of two sizes required to be allocated.

Comment: @JorgWMittag: (I realize this is an old thread) It may be bumping a pointer but access to that allocation is at least one cache miss (perhaps more) because of pointer dereference which is significant enough to be a topic of quite a bit of research in academia (see some IBM papers - among others). Stack allocated objects suffer much less here because the stack is most likely hot in the cache.

Answer (score 3):

At least as I read it, your real question is whether there have been significant developments in garbage collection or manual memory management since that paper was published that would invalidate its results. The answer to that is somewhat mixed. On one hand, the vendors who provide garbage collectors do tune them so their performance tends to improve over time. On the other hand, there hasn't been anything like a major breakthroughs such as major new garbage collection algorithms.

Manual heap managers generally improve over time as well. I doubt most are tuned with quite the regularity of garbage collectors, but in the course of 5 years, probably most have had at least a bit of work done.

In short, both have undoubtedly improved at least a little, but in neither case have there been major new algorithms that change the fundamental landscape. It's doubtful that current implementations will give a difference of exactly 17% as quoted in the article, but there's a pretty good chance that if you repeated the tests today, you'd still get a difference somewhere around 15-20% or so. The differences between then and now are probably *smaller* than the differences between some of the different algorithms they tested at that time.

Comment: What are “manual heap managers”? Doesn’t “manual heap management” imply the absence of a manager, in other words, that the programmer manages the heap, regardless of whether they have thirty years of experience or are beginners?

Comment: @Holger: A manual heap manager is (in simple terms) the implementation of `new` and `delete` in C++. The user decides what to allocate and free (and when to do so, etc.) but there's some code there to keep track of what blocks of memory are free, what are in use, finds you a block of sufficient size when you do an allocation, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how relivent your question still is today.  A performance critical application shouldn't spend a sigificant portion of its time doing object creation (as the micro-benchmark is very likely to do) and the performance on modern systems is more likely to be determined by how well the application fits into the CPUs cache, rather than how much main memory it uses.

BTW: There are lots of ticks you can do in C++ which support this which are not available in Java.

If you are worried about the cost of GC or object creation, you can take steps to minimise how many objects you create.  This is generally a good idea where performance is critical in any language.

The cost of main memory isn't as much of an issue as it used to me.  A machine with 48 GB is relatively cheap these days. An 8 core server with 48 GB of main memory can be leased for £9/day.  Try hiring a developer for £9/d. ;)  However, what is still relatively expensive is CPU cache memory.  It is fairly hard to find a system with more than 16 MB of CPU cache. c.f. 48,000 MB of main memory.  A system performs much better when an application is using its CPU cache and this is the amount of memory to consider if performance is critical.

Answer (score -1):

First note that its now 2019 and a lot of things has improved.
As long as you dont trigger GC, allocation would be like as simple as incrementing a pointer. In C++ its much more if you dont implement your own mechanism to allocate in chunks.
And if you use smart shared pointers each change to refercence count will required locked increment (xaddl instruction) is slow itself and requires processors communicate to invalidate and resynch their cacheline.
What is more, with GC you get more locality with at least three ways. First when it allocates a new segment, it zero's memory and warms cachelines. Second it compacts heap and cause data to stay closer togeter and lastly all threads use its own heap.
In conclusion, although its hard to test and compare with every scenario and GC implementation ive read somewhere on SO that its proven GC performs better than manual memory management.