# When would you ever want to keep a non-allocated object in memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management

This is a question in regards to non garbage-collected languages (C, C++, etc).

I've been told that one of the things that makes C++ faster than something like C# is the built-in garbage collection having the potential to slow things down. In addition, I've been told there are use cases for keeping deallocated memory on the stack.

As for the latter, I've never been given an example beyond:

> Minecraft had issues with performance early on because it was written in Java and not C++ because of garbage collection.

I'm wondering if any of this has validity, and if there is any reason to not immediately delete any allocated objects as soon as all references to them are lost?

Comment: In C++ "you don't pay for what you don't need". Reference counting to know when object can or cannot be deleted takes additional resources. C++ executables are very predictable because there is no random mechanism in the background, like garbage collector that might or might not decide to free some memory. "use cases for keeping deallocated memory on the stack" - the what, firs time hear about it?

Comment: I could imagine one reason being that when you delete an object, you then have to check any objects it referenced to see if they also need to be GC'd. Depending on the complexity of your objects, this can take a significant amount of time. Also, deallocating an object may also involve zeroing out the object's memory to ensure a consistent state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982325/quantifying-the-performance-of-garbage-collection-vs-explicit-memory-management

Comment: GC either relies on some means of tracking how many references there are to allocated objects, some form of scanning to find which objects are no longer being referenced, or both. In C++, such tracking or scanning is often not actually required.   Such tracking or scanning introduces runtime overhead (memory usage or processor cycles (or both)).   There are use cases for keeping allocated memory alive even if not needed, as a performance optimisation for the memory management (e.g. avoiding repeated deallocation and reallocation of memory) but such cases exist with or without a GC.

Comment: Before we become too entrenched in out beliefs that C and C++ are not garbage collected, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collect. To my mind at least, garbage collectors are a bit like allowing you to delay cleaning your house until just before your wife returns home.

Comment: @Bathsheba Fixed your link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector

Comment: @user17732522: Oh you are nice.

Comment: C++ has available ways to do something cheaper or even free compared to heap memory management. There are three other types of storage (global static, thread local static and automatic) besides heap (dynamic) plus there is value semantics available that makes the storage of sub-objects (like elements of arrays and data members) managed in one go with storage of composite. Also it all is managed quite conveniently so I haven't had to type new or delete into my C++ code for past 15 years or so.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, allocated memory is never on the stack, with the exception of compilers that provide the `alloca()` function. In which case, the memory will be freed at the end of the function.

As for performance: a good GC generally runs at the same speed as `malloc()`/`free()`. Both methods have overhead, but it's about the same. Obviously, you can always find an exception to the rule. And Java's GC hasn't always been a good GC.

In games, or anything else that synchronizes to video output, you also want to tune the GC to run once per frame, instead of having it trigger at random times. Otherwise, you easily get a stutter every time the GC triggers. That is not because the GC is slow, but because deallocation is delayed until it suddenly happens all at once. It just throws off the timing.

Comment: .Net core 3+ and .Net 5/6/7's biggest advances are actually centered around stack-allocated objects using `stackalloc` and stored as `Span<>`. Stack allocation has a very big positive impact on the GC since it doesn't need to track allocations to the root to determine when they're finalizable, and they're trivial to actually free (the natural stack unwinding takes care of it for you).

Answer (score -1):

> I’m wondering if any of this has validity and if there is any reason to not immediately deleted any allocated objects as soon as all references to them are lost?

That's how all modern GCs work, they only trigger when the memory pressure increase reaches a set threshold (ie too many allocations in a short time, or when your used memory % gets close to the available 100%).

The reason for that is multi-threading. When all threads hold a reference to a piece of memory, moving it around as a result of a garbage collection and compacting pass will let the threads other than the GC's thread use it as normal, so if that becomes the case the GC has to freeze all other threads, do its work, and then unfreeze everything, which is very expensive. So instead it keeps objects alive in memory until there's an actual *need* for memory to be freed. Memory is there to be used, after all.

> Minecraft had issues with performance early on because it was written in Java and not C++ because of garbage collection

If anything, it probably has issues because Java doesn't have value types and every single integer is an actual class object with everything that implies (managed box with a pointer to the actual data, synchonization mutex fields, etc). This has nothing to do with the garbage collector or with the aforementioned C# however.

Comment: *Java doesn't have value types* it has both a primitive `int` and a class `Integer`, altough there's only like 7 primitive types that one can use, all arrays go on the heap etc.

Comment: Now it does (since Java SE 8, actually), not when Minecraft came out, which was OP's question. Do you have something on topic to add to the conversation?

Comment: Autoboxing/unboxing is a [feature of Java 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#boxing), and I'm quite sure primitives existed since the dawn of Java (but I can't find source for that). Still, even Java 5 predates Minecraft.

Comment: Autoboxing is exactly what I'm talking about, the values are sored as objects (boxes) and the system transparently unboxes them and reboxes them as needed.

Comment: In fact it is/used to be so bad that Java had a cache of integers between -127 and 128 stored as an internal array of `Integer` objects, so when you calculated one you'd get one of those objects. And because they are objects, you could use reflection to *change the value of basic integers*, and your code would just silently use the new value. There's a (in)famous `thedailywtf.com` article about exactly this.

Comment: Autoboxing is implicit conversion from `int` (primitive) to `Integer` (class). Unboxing is implicit conversion from `Integer` to `int`. Primitives are not stored as boxes, primitives are stored on the stack directly. Java does not change primitive to a class by itself, you have declare the type as `Integer` or `int`. Autoboxing/unboxing simply reduces boilerplate from converting one to the other. And well, I guess caching helps with performance when you can't use a primitive (because there can't be a collection of primitive) and it works it because `Integer` objects are immutable anyway.